# How to set datagrid as viewed?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to bind data from several datagrids and I don't want to view all of them every time I start app. 
Is there any possibility to set it in settings? Or automaticaly set all datagrids as viewed?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't show only those that you want to view at any particular time?

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to show/view them. I just want to bind/convert the data from them.

Comment: The `DataGrid` is a GUI control.  It will bind to an underlying data item when it is initialised.  Either you already have the data and there's no need for the DataGrid, or the user enters the data and it has to be shown for the for the user to enter it.

Comment: You could set it's `Visibile` property to `false` before calling the `InitializeComponent` method (usually done in the class constructor).  You'll probably have to give it an owner too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your thinking about this the wrong way? If you want your data before the table is shown what you need to do is get and store the data in a `DataTable` and then use that to play with. Then when it comes to displaying your `DataGridView` just simply bind the `DataTable` to it and display it. I have included a sample below. But if its just a case of showing the tables then either `tablename.visable = false` should do the trick or alternitivly if you have other elements such as a panel you could use `panelname.BringToFront` or `tablename.SendToBack`.

Lets begin the OOP example..

This you could have in another interface class where you want to manipulate the data. In this example this class would be `IOptions`, here you could have all the data tables you need for Options for example. You could have different Interface Classes representing certain parts of your program, but we will stick with options for now..

```
               public DataTable mProgramOptionsList;
```

Then when the program starts (your main page / main.cs) you attach IOptions to any of the classes that need at this `DataTable`.

```
                mIOptions = new IOptions();

                mPresenterOptions = new PresenterOptions();
                mPresenterOptions.AttachInterface(mIOptions);

                mModelOptions = new ModelOptions();
                mModelOptions.AttachInterface(mIOptions);
```

Example code in `PresenterOptions()`

```
                IOptions mIOptions;

                public void AttachInterface(IOptions pOptions)
                {
                    mIOptions = pOptions;
                }
```

Now in Presenter Options you can modify the tables as you please, as well as fill them..

```
                mIOptions.mProgramOptionsList = mModelOptions.GetProgOptionsFromDB();
```

This is the class you want to have your table control in. This could be a separate GUI/View class with its own layout and structure. As long as you have attached the Interface (`IOptions`) to the class your using to hold all your tables.

```
    private IOptions mIOptions;

    private BindingSource mbsProgramOptions;

    public int mOptionsID { get; set; }

    void AttachOptionsInterface(IOptions pOptions)
    {
        mIOptions = pOptions;
        CreateDataBindings();
    }

    private void CreateDataBindings()
    {
        mbsProgramOptions= new BindingSource();
        mbsProgramOptions.DataSource = mIOptions.mProgramOptionsList; // Or what ever datatable you have made
        dgvProgramOptions.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dgvProgramOptions.DataSource = mbsProgramOptions; // this binds your DataGridView to the DataSource
    }
```

Once this is done not only can you add or change the data to any class you have attached IOptions too you can also display the table anywhere you please by just doing something like (Assuming you called your table control class above `TableHelper`):

In the PresenterOptions or any class for that matter:

```
        TableHelper ProgramOptionsList;

        ProgramOptionsList.mOptionsID = 1234; // Accessing a public/get;set; variable in TableHelper Class
        ProgramOptionsList.Text = "Table Title";
        ProgramOptionsList.ShowDialog();
        ProgramOptionsList.BringToFront(); // Just in case you have multiple tables over lapping each other in TableHelper
```